# Созданный пользователь не проходит аутентификацию Djnago

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model

Мне нужно создать пользователя через админ панель. Что бы он потом мог зайти на сайт(в будущем планируется разграничение доступа)
Я наследуюсь от модели `AbstractUser`

`models.py`:

```
class AdvUser(AbstractUser):

    position = models.ForeignKey('JobTitle', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 max_length=100,  verbose_name="Должность работника",
                                 related_name='positions',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'


class JobTitle(models.Model):  # Должность работника
    position = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.position}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Должность работника'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Должности работников'
```

В `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'logic_TORA.AdvUser'
```

`views.py`:

```
def loginPage(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('logic_TORA:home')
        else:
            # messages.info(request, 'Username or password incorrect')

            print('не вошел')
            print(user)
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', context)


def logout_request(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, "registration/logged_out.html", context)


def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

`admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(AdvUser)
class AdminViewAdvUser(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'position',)
    search_fields = ('first_name',)
    list_filter = ('position', 'groups')


@admin.register(JobTitle)
class AdminViewJobTitle(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('position',)
```

`urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'logic_TORA'


urlpatterns = [

    path("login/", loginPage, name="login"),
    path("logout/", logout_request, name='logout'),
    path('', home, name='home'),
```

`login.html`:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<main>
    <div class="p-3">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Вы уже выполнили вход</p>


{% else %}
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="text" name="username" >
        <input type="password" name="password" >
        <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
{%endif%}
    </div></main>
{% endblock %}
```

Я могу зайти от суперюзера на сайт(в админку и так захожу ,всё нормально) и меня редиректит на `home.html`
Но когда я создаю пользователя в админ панели и через него пытаюся зайти на сайт(не в админку!) то форма обновляется и ничего не происходит.
Во `views` я написал `print(user)` в котором мне после ввода пароля в консоли пишет `None`.
Я не могу понять почему так происходит. Я думаю это может быть связано с тем что я наследуюсь от `AbstractUser` но не вижу связи. помогите пожалуйста.
bd [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавльте юзеру `is_staff = True` в админке, иначе не войдете в админку. Если доступ в админку не нужен. то не пытайтесь туда редиректить

Comment: @ZaArs  мне не нужно что бы обычный юзер заходил в админку. мне нужно что бы он просто мог попасть на сайт.

Comment: покажите какой пароль вводите и что хранится в бд

Comment: @ZaArs прикреплю скриншот, редактирую вопрос

Comment: пароль для узера надо устанавливать через `set_password()`. так как он не зашифрован, джанго пытается сравнить с зашифрованным вариантом - авторизация не проходит.

Comment: @ZaArs А где именно?

Comment: при создании/регистрации

Answer (score 0):

Я переписал модели и все получилось.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='Пользователь',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, verbose_name='Группа', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    position = models.OneToOneField('JobTitle', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 max_length=100,  verbose_name="Должность работника",
                                 related_name='positions', null=True)


class JobTitle(models.Model):  # Должность работника
    position = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.position}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Должность работника'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Должности работников'
```